# Animate an ImageView by saving starting and ending position

Tags: android, animation, imageview

I have an `ImageView` which can be moved by finger with a `touchListener`. I want the user to save two positions of the `Imageview` by pressing a button and after that, when he press to play the `animation`, to start from the first position and finish to the second. 
How this can be possible? I try by saving in an array the two position by using `getX` and `getY` and after put them in a `TranslateAnimation`, but it doesn't work

```
public void get1Cos(){
        x[1] = player.getX();
        y[1] = player.getY();
}
public void get2Cos(){
        x[6] = player.getX();
        y[6] = player.getY();
}
anim = new TranslateAnimation(x[1], x[6], y[1],y[6]);
anim.setFillAfter(true);
anim.setDuration(2000);
player.startAnimation(anim);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
player.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: I try this. Simply I didn't put here because I forgot it. I fix it.

Comment: animate yes, but it starts and finish in positions relative to its current position and not fron the position I have saved

Comment: I believe you should use this constructor:  TranslateAnimation (Animation.ABSOLUTE, x[1], Animation.ABSOLUTE, x[6], Animation.ABSOLUTE, y[1], Animation.ABSOLUTE, y[6])

Comment: from documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html#TranslateAnimation(int, float, int, float, int, float, int, float)

Comment: because the animation starts relative to the current position, I try to setX and setY in the start position when I saved the last position, but when after that I try to run the animation, it only changes the position and not animate.

Comment: did you try using the constructor with the Animation.ABSOLUTE?

Comment: My friend I found it!
I put TranslateAnimation(x[1]-x[6],0,y[1]-y[6],0) and it works properly!!!

Comment: Great! I guess I didn't understand what you wanted to achieve